# Accessing OneDrive file - the easiest way

Tags: xamarin.android

My android app needs to access (read only) .txt file located on OneDrive. Which is the simplest way to achieve that? All tutorial I read are a bit complicated for me (I'm new in this android stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to share the file read only using “anyone anonymous with the link”. So basically no log in is required to access the file, just the link generated by onedrive. Using that link you should be able to access the file directly like any http web link.

Cheers
Christian

Comment: Yes, this simple idea should work! thank you, Sir.

Comment: @niepewnyjutra If the answer helps you, please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).